# RL vs RLC circuit magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

If I want to create an alternating magnetic field using an inductor, what difference would it make to use a series RL or a series RLC circuit ?
How will the presence of a capacitor affect the magnetic field ?

Comment: Well, you haven't specified what type of voltage source you're using. Surely it's an alternating circuit?

Comment: Yes, that would be on alternating current.